# SORT is not working in Aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation, mongo-go

I have this code to Mongo in Golang

```
    cond := make([]bson.M, 0)
    cond = append(condiciones, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"userId": ID}})
    cond = append(condiciones, bson.M{
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "invoices",
            "localField":   "userId",
            "foreignField": "userId",
            "as":           "sales",
        }})
    cond = append(condiciones, bson.M{"$unwind": "$sales"})
    cond = append(condiciones, bson.M{"$skip": skip})
    cond = append(condiciones, bson.M{"$limit": 100})
    cond = append(condiciones, bson.M{"$sort": bson.M{"dateInvoice": -1}})

    cursor, err := collect.Aggregate(context.TODO(), cond)
```

I'm using Golang and MongoDB

```
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
```

this works fine in union, limit and skipping documents, but the $sort doesn't work.. I have invoices but not ordered by 'dateInvoice'

I'm desperate.. please

What's wrong in my code ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.

Instead

```
cond = append(condiciones, bson.M{"$sort": bson.M{"dateInvoice": -1}})
```

Is necessary write

```
cond = append(condiciones, bson.M{"$sort": bson.M{"sales.dateInvoice": -1}})
```

Because the $sort, try to find the 'dateInvoice' in the initial collection 'users' and the dateInvoice field is in the sales collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the `$sort` before the `$skip` and `$limit` operations, else there is no guarantee the documents are listed in the same order when the query is repeated (optionally with different pagination parameters), which could result in "random" results. The `$sort` at the end only guarantees that the restricted max 100 documents will be sorted.

Sort first, so you get consistent behavior (given there are no invoices with the same `dateInvoice` timestamp).

Comment: Thanks icza, but I haven't any sorted document.. not in the 100 results, then.. $sort is not working

Comment: And you get no error? Is `dateInvoice` spelled the same as in the DB?